# How to set condition on UIView

Tags: ios, if-statement, uiview

I want to put If condition on UIView. If the subView appears the button should be disabled. but i done know the syntax of how to put condition on UIView. I would be really thankful if any one can guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your view is appear means, your view is in `view's hierarchy`, that means, your view's window property will be not nil, you can check with this condition.

```
if (view.window != nil)
{
    //button disable 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you want your condition based on subview so you have to use subview property of view like this:

```
 if(yourView.subviews.count>0)

{

your code for disable button

}
```